# Partial string matching

Tags: php, string-matching

I'm making a small system for personal use on that I want to handle files. In this system I want to categorize files based on names and automate as much as possible. This has lead me to a problem with matching strings.

Say I have a category called `A category` and a two files called:

1. `a.category.file`
2. `lotsofgarbage.a-big-kateory.file`

I need to match these file names to the category. I guess it would be more like a "how much is they alike" score, since there is no good way to do an exact match.

Can anyone give me a simple an good algorithm for this problem? Or point me in the direction of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to tackle this, would be to calculate the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) of your filenames to your category name, and if they're under a certain treshold, then they should match.

Check out [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), apparently php can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this (easier): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Or this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: What makes you say similar_text() is easier to use?

Comment: Because maybe you don't need the functionality of Levenshtein.
I think you can solve your problem using Similar_text, but for completeness you can solve with Lenshtein too.